# PHP to convert string to array

Tags: php

This may be asked several times but my case is a bit different.

Let me start from the beginning.

```
$ck_data = db_select('ckeditor_settings', 'cs')
           ->fields('cs', array('settings'))
           ->condition('name', 'Advanced', '=')
           ->execute()
           ->fetchAssoc();
var_dump($ck_data);
```

Will give me...

```
array(1) {
  ["settings"]=>
  string(2144) "a:33:{s:2:"ss";s:1:"2";s:7:"toolbar";s:606:"[
    ['Source'],
    ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','SpellChecker','Scayt'],
    ['Undo','Redo','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll'],
    ['Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar'],
    ['Maximize','ShowBlocks'],
    '/',
    ['Format'],
    ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat'],
    ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
    ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl'],
    ['Link','Unlink','Anchor','Linkit','LinkToNode','LinkToMenu']
]";s:6:"expand";s:1:"t";s:7:"default";s:1:"t";s:11:"show_toggle";s:1:"t";s:7:"uicolor";s:7:"default";s:12:"uicolor_user";s:7:"default";s:5:"width";s:4:"100%";s:4:"lang";s:2:"en";s:9:"auto_lang";s:1:"t";s:18:"language_direction";s:7:"default";s:15:"allowed_content";s:1:"t";s:19:"extraAllowedContent";s:0:"";s:10:"enter_mode";s:1:"p";s:16:"shift_enter_mode";s:2:"br";s:11:"font_format";s:35:"p;div;pre;address;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6";s:17:"custom_formatting";s:1:"f";s:10:"formatting";a:1:{s:25:"custom_formatting_options";a:6:{s:6:"indent";s:6:"indent";s:15:"breakBeforeOpen";s:15:"breakBeforeOpen";s:14:"breakAfterOpen";s:14:"breakAfterOpen";s:15:"breakAfterClose";s:15:"breakAfterClose";s:16:"breakBeforeClose";i:0;s:10:"pre_indent";i:0;}}s:8:"css_mode";s:4:"none";s:8:"css_path";s:0:"";s:9:"css_style";s:5:"theme";s:11:"styles_path";s:0:"";s:11:"filebrowser";s:4:"none";s:17:"filebrowser_image";s:0:"";s:17:"filebrowser_flash";s:0:"";s:13:"UserFilesPath";s:5:"%b%f/";s:21:"UserFilesAbsolutePath";s:7:"%d%b%f/";s:21:"forcePasteAsPlainText";s:1:"t";s:13:"html_entities";s:1:"f";s:17:"scayt_autoStartup";s:1:"t";s:15:"theme_config_js";s:1:"f";s:7:"js_conf";s:0:"";s:11:"loadPlugins";a:1:{s:12:"drupalbreaks";a:5:{s:4:"name";s:12:"drupalbreaks";s:4:"desc";s:51:"Plugin for inserting Drupal teaser and page breaks.";s:4:"path";s:25:"%plugin_dir%drupalbreaks/";s:7:"buttons";a:1:{s:11:"DrupalBreak";a:2:{s:5:"label";s:11:"DrupalBreak";s:4:"icon";s:22:"images/drupalbreak.png";}}s:7:"default";s:1:"t";}}}"
}
```

Now what I want is to get the value of `toolbar`.

```
$ck_settings = unserialize($ck_data['settings']);
$ck_plugins = $ck_settings['toolbar'];
var_dump($ck_plugins);
```

Will return...

```
string(606) "[
    ['Source'],
    ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','SpellChecker','Scayt'],
    ['Undo','Redo','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll'],
    ['Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar'],
    ['Maximize','ShowBlocks'],
    '/',
    ['Format'],
    ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat'],
    ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
    ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl'],
    ['Link','Unlink','Anchor','Linkit','LinkToNode','LinkToMenu']
]"
```

My question now is how can I convert `$ck_plugins` from string to array?

Comment: look at PHP's documentation on [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: I already tried that but seems like not a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

Strange way to be storing that, but it is a string that looks like a PHP array definition:

```
eval("\$ck_plugins = $ck_plugins;");
print_r($ck_plugins);
```

If you have control over the data storage, you should probably either store the individual entries in a table or store the entire thing serialized or better in JSON.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Convert the string to array is what you asked.

Comment: Yeah...This is I think the closest solution after several hours of trial. Thanks AbraCadaver

Comment: It would have been better to just store that serialized (or the whole column) as well, but it looks like it was meant to be stored as the source of a PHP array definition.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - can you tell me what `eval("\$ck_plugins = $ck_plugins;");` does? I know that `eval` is used to "evaluate" code - but I do not quite understand how it works in this case...

Comment: It's taking that [[],[],[]] type string stored in `$ck_plugins` which is the same as an array definition in PHP and evaluating it as code so that the array is assigned to the variable `$ck_plugins`.  You could replace the `"\$ck_plugins = $ck_plugins;"` with `"\$result = $ck_plugins;"` and then use `$result`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois:  Can be with user supplied input, but not always.  It's very useful.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The question is, why is he storing a php array definition in his database. He should rather store the serialized *real* array in the database.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: Agreed.  I mentioned that, but sometimes you work with the data you have.  Since they didn't know what it was it's probable that they didn't store it.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois that's the way how the plugin (3rd party) stored the data.